# How to find records from one table whose child table has duplicate values?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are three tables like below:

```
shields:
id  | name 
----------
122 | Diagnosis


monitors:
id   |  name |  sheild_id 
-------------------------
12   | xxxx  |   122
13   | yyyy  |   122
14   | zzzz  |   122
15   | aaaa  |   125

entries:
id   | entry_type  | state
---------------------
12   | MISS  | DONE
13   | MISS  | DONE
14   | MR.   | DONE
18   | MISS  | INPROGRESS
19   | MR.   | DONE
24   | MS.   | DONE
```

I need a query which let me know the `sheild_id` whose `entry_type` is repeated. Basically there should be unique `entry_type`. In the above case, the result will be 122.

Help, would be really appreciated.

Comment: How are the tables connected?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `monitors.id` links to `entries.id`, the following returns the shields that have multiple entries for a given entry type:

```
select m.shield_id, e.entry_type
from monitors m join
     entries e
     on m.id = e.id
group by m.shield_id, e.entry_type
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Works well for me !! Thanks a ton !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
s.id shield_id,
e.entry_type,
count(*) nr_duplicates
from
  shields s
  left outer join monitors m on m.sheild_id = s.id
  left outer join entries e on e.id = m.id
GROUP BY s.id, e.entry_type
having count(*) > 1
```